# How to shutdown vm from vnet gracefully?

Tags: networking, shutdown, vmware-workstation, network-adapter, failover

I use VMware Workstation Pro with one DC vm and three ordinary vms. All vms are located in the one domain and in the one virtual network. Virtual adapters are used in order to connect vm into vnet. My question is is it possible to make clean shutdown of the vm from the vnet?

I tried the following options but unfortunately couldn't get desired result:

1. disabling virtual adapter from ncpa.cpl
2. disabling IPv4 and IPv6 from virtual adapter properties
3. disconnecting virtual adapter from vmware interface

I would like to know if it really possible to do this and if yes the could you suggest a way to do it?

P.S how do I know whether shutdown was clean or sudden? -> I am testing failover situations in windows server failover cluster and dynamic quorum feature does not work properly in case of sudden failures such as sudden network or cluster service shutdown. For example, when I kill the cluster service from task manager dynamic quorum does not work correctly, however when I shutdown cluster service from services.msc then it is ok and dynamic quorum works properly and reassigning of votes happens correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the "vmrun" command to shut down a VMware Workstation by command line.  This is the main command for this purpose and the shut down is a normal shutdown.

[Shut down guest by command line](https://petri.com/virtual_administer_vmware_workstation_from_command_line#:%7E:text=The%20main%20command%2Dline%20program,type%20vmrun%20and%20press%20Enter.)

> The main command-line program used to stop and start VMware
> Workstation Virtual machines is the vmrun command. If you open the
> Windows cmd prompt and change directory to C:’Program
> Files’VMware’VMware Server. Once there, type vmrun and press Enter.

Also  [Vmrun examples](https://hyper-v-backup.backupchain.com/vmware-workstation-start-stop-vms-from-command-line/)

1. To start a virtual machine:

> "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun" -T ws start
> "C:\VMs\Linux.vmx"

2. To Shut down a VM:

> C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun" -T ws stop
> "C:\VMs\Linux.vmx"

3. To reboot:

> "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun" -T ws reset
> "C:\VMs\Linux.vmx"

Comment: Knowing these commands is very useful with the new autostart feature in WS v12. Whilst autostart will start the VM, running under the SYSTEM account by default, you can't interact with it from the VMware Workstation app. The recommendation is if you do need to interact, use remote desktop or suspend the VM. You have to use vmrun.exe to suspend it. Additionally, use psexec.exe to run the vmrun.exe command as the SYSTEM account.